# cannot get /ID (querystring) Express, nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm very new to Express and nodeJS.
I'm working around with query string and dynamic web page and it says that cannot get id.
I have no idea where I did go wrong.
Any help would be appreciated!

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const fs = require('fs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    fs.readdir('./data', (err, list) => {
        fs.readFile(`data/${req.query.id}`, 'utf8', (err, data)=>{
            if(!req.query.id){
                req.query.id = "Welcome";
                data = "Hello World";
            }
            res.send(`<html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
            <h1><a href="#">Web<a></h1>
            <ul>
            ${list.map(item=>`<li><a href="/id?=${item}">${item}</a></li>`).join('')}
            </ul>
            <a href="create">Create</a>
            <h2>${req.query.id}</h2>
            <p>${data}</p>
            </body>
            </html>`)
        })
    })
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Comment: What is the **exact** error message you're seeing?

Comment: @Pointy my bad. the error says `Cannot GET /id`

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are calling url like "/id" and you are trying get a query string.
For get id as variable on url, you must put on path like:

```
app.get("/:id", (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
})
```

If you want get a query string, use:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    const id = req.query.id;
})
```

You need call url like:  /?id=1

Answer (score 0):

I found out.. it's `"/?id=${item}"` , not `"/id?=${item}"`